# What is the difference between File.SetCreationTime() and File.SetCreationTimeUtc()

Tags: datetime, file-io, ntfs, fat32, file-properties

In particular, is there any difference between these two lines in terms of their outcomes:

```
File.SetCreationTime("foo.txt", DateTime.UtcNow);
File.SetCreationTimeUtc("foo.txt", DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Perhaps `File.SetCreationTimeUtc("foo.txt", DateTime.Now)` is just another way of doing `File.SetCreationTime("foo.txt", DateTime.UtcNow)`?

The same question applies to `File.SetLastAccessTime()` vs. `File.SetLastAccessTimeUtc()` and `File.SetLastWriteTime()` vs. `File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one will set the wrong time because it is expecting a date expressed in your local time zone.